# Unpause a rails server that was paused in a different terminal window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, unix, terminal

I'm on mac osx using zsh. If I start a rails server with "rails s" I can put it in the background by hitting "ctrl-z" in my terminal (zsh).

If I open up a different terminal window then I don't see the rails server if I do "jobs". However, I can see it when I do "ps".

Is there a way I can somehow "unpause" the rails server in this new terminal window?

Comment: I flagged this question as off topic: It is really about handling processes on a *nix system, not about Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I disagree, this problem came up because I'm working on a rails app. I figure a rails dev will have just as good a chance at knowing the answer than a *nix user. Though I will concede that the "ruby" tag is probably not the most appropriate.

Comment: Fair enough, but still: It is a universal *nix/processes problem and somebody over at ServerFault probably knows better. We are devs, not *nix specialists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not easily [move a process to a new tty](http://blog.habets.pp.se/2009/03/Moving-a-process-to-another-terminal). The easiest solution would be to start it in a [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) session, detach screen and then resume in the new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The job is "stopped" by sending it a `SIGSTOP`.Your `C-z` doesn't send the job into the background. It "stops" it. You can then move it into the background using the `bg` shell builtin. However, if you send this process a SIGCONT (`kill -CONT <pid>`), it should bring the process back to the foreground. This can be done from a different shell.

You will not see it if you type `jobs` because it is a job controlled by a different shell (the other terminal window and not the one where you typed jobs). Processes however are "global" and can be seen from anywhere using the `ps` command (as you rightly pointed out).

**Update**: Looks like I spoke too soon. Apparently, the signal alone isn't enough to bring it back to the foreground. Probably something to do with the shell.